# Can information about git/svn checkout and other usefull info be accessed from the generated files?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, cvs

First let me explain why I need this question answered, so you can better understand my problem.

I am trying to make easy backup of folders that contain source files, and backup only the essential files. One of the steps that I need to do for this is remove the .svn/.git/etc. folders, because they contain a lot of files.

But I do want to keep the information about the checkout server, for example.

Is there any way to parse those files in order to retrieve this information? And if so, what do I have to look for?

Comment: Do you want CVS information? The tag has been added, but it's not explicitly mentioned in the title or the question.

Comment: Backup only Working Dir without repo (for Git) is, at least, "funny"! You **must to backup repos**, because WDs are easy  recorerable from repositories

Comment: BTW, I'll fire even Senior (Junior - even faster) for such "backup"

Comment: Hello. I completely forgot about this question. My mistake, I wasn't clear with the question. I wanted to backup information about the repositories. In that case, I had a lot of projects, and it seemed like a lot of work to copy everything into another place, or clone and checkout at the revision I was on. So it would be simpler to just find a file where all this info is, and create a script to do all the cloning and checking out for me. Of course the repo is still there, and I use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to capture .git/config. It contains information about the remote repository:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = gitolite@prscgitapp01.aligntech.com:platform/playground/BackendsManager
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "SessionAllocator"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/SessionAllocator
[branch "alevin_testconfigs"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/alevin_testconfigs
```